# Footer is not cooperating and comments box has disappeared

Tags: html, css, wordpress

so I have a site http://theuntoldspiral.com/test-post/dfgfdgfd/, I can't get the footer to cooperate with the various fluid heights of posts, and for some reason that is completely beyond me the comments box has disappeared.

The code is quite long, but you can see what I am talking about with the site. Any help would be appreciated, and I do apologise in advance if the code is messy/unconventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have floated elements in your container div. Floated items don't expand its container. This is a [clearfix issue.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

This fixed your page:

```
div#content-container:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is code, this also work perfectly for your case.

```
   .outer-wrapper {
      width: 69%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```